# Simple storage for relay starter kit

Tags: relay, graphql, relayjs

I'm learning Relay and GraphQL with the Relay starter kit from Facebook. I want to create a simple storage for my data, basically just to keep my GraphQL mutations somewhere. I will deal with a proper ORM and database later.

Could I just dump the data as JSON into a flat file? How would I do this? (No need for concurrency, security and such, I'm still learning all of this.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone who knows the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is going to be to keep the objects in memory, as [the starter kit example does](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit/blob/f17360ba115e853bb0ee63442a643d98ac4b2852/data/database.js).

So, yes, you could store it as a JSON file and `require` that if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you! At what point would I insert the command to dump everything from memory to a file that I then require again? Sorry, I'm really new to this. :-/